# Ajax trava o computador

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

Analise o código abaixo

```
function update(){
  $.ajax({
    url  : 'http://localhost/sistema',
    type : 'get',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function( data ){
      console.log('Mostrar dados: '+.data.dado);
    }
  })
}


setInterval(function () { update() }, 3000);
```

O ajax manda uma requisição 'get' para o servidor que retorna com os dados.

Até aí tudo bem.

Essa requisição é feita a cada três (3) segundos

Só que aproximadamente depois de umas 20 execuções o computador tudo começa a travar.

O backend está em Laravel com MySQL

Testando pelo PostMan ele retorna rapido e normal

Será que tem algo a ver com o PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O recomendado é colocar o temporizador após o término do Ajax (`complete`), como `setTimeout` e não `setInterval`. Isso porque, como o Ajax é assíncrono, o `setInterval` irá sempre executar a função que chama o Ajax sem esperar que a requisição anterior seja completada, e isso pode criar um gargalo enorme de requisições, sobrecarregando o servidor e o navegador, resultando em travamentos.

Coloque um `setTimeout` no `complete` do Ajax e chame a função ao carregar a página. Desta forma, uma nova requisição só será feita 3 segundos após a anterior ter sido completada:

```
function update(){
  $.ajax({
    url  : 'http://localhost/sistema',
    type : 'get',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function( data ){
      console.log('Mostrar dados: '+.data.dado);
    },
    complete: function(){
      setTimeout(function () { update() }, 3000);
    }
  })
}

update();
```