# Interromper o setInterval para uma função executar em seu lugar?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um código que faz uma consulta no banco de dados (de 1 em 1 segundo) utilizando o **setInterval** e atualiza um painel (Via AJAX e PHP), do meu sistema, que mostra o resumo de todas as tarefas do usuário. (Para dar a impressão ao usuário que é em tempo real e ele veja a alteração do painel quando ele alterar algo no sistema).

**PROBLEMA:** O problema é que tenho um filtro e gostaria que, ao selecionar determinadas empresas, o painel só mostrasse as atividades de determinada empresa (e não de todas, como é feito por padrão). Só que isso não acontece, porque o setInverval fica rodando o tempo todo.

**Abaixo, vou mostrar uma imagem do sistema:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que a descrição foi meio genérica, mas se puderem me dar uma luz, eu agradeço.

Obrigado!

Comment: O [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Return_value) retorna o ID do timer criado. Para pará-lo basta usar este ID como argumento para a função [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

Comment: De repente, dentro do setInterval, deixe a função verificando o que tem no campo cliente, e atualiza a busca com o valor que o usuario selecionar. Para ser mais preciso teria que ver o codigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É como o @fernandosavio falou. O setInterval() precisa de um identificador, por exemplo:

```
timer = setInterval(function(){

   //executa ações

}, 1000);
```

Para para-lo, usa-se o identificador atribuído ao setInterval():

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

Porém, não é recomendável usar setInterval para fazer requisições AJAX, como explicado [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/293670/8063). O certo mesmo é usar `setTimeout()` chamando uma função que chama o AJAX após ele ser processado. Ao usar setInterval() para esse propósito você poderá estressar (sobrecarregar) o servidor e o navegador, conforme explicado na resposta mencionada.